# R Shiny - add JS files to HTML Template

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I try to use my R Shinyapp with an HTML Template like this:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
##
}

ui <- function() {
  htmlTemplate("dist/index.html")
}

# Serve the files in the js folder
if (dir.exists("dist")) {
  addResourcePath("js", "dist")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I just open the index.html in my browser, everything works, but not in combination with shiny. The js files in my index html are linked like this: `<script src=js/chunk-vendors.b0f460c7.js>`.

[image]

I tried to add a resource path with `addResourcePath`, but I was not able to get it work. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Do I have to change my paths in the html or is my code in R wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This solves it :)

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  histogramData <- reactive({
    req(input$bins)
    x <- faithful$waiting
    breaks <- round(seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1), 1)
    dist <- hist(x, breaks = breaks, plot = FALSE)
    list(
      breaks = breaks,
      counts = dist$counts,
      ticks = pretty(breaks)
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage("histogramData", histogramData())
  })
}

ui <- function() {
  htmlTemplate("dist/index.html")
}

# Serve the bundle at js/main.js
if (dir.exists("dist/js")) {
  addResourcePath("js", "dist/js")
}

# Serve the bundle at js/main.js
if (dir.exists("dist/css")) {
  addResourcePath("css", "dist/css")
}

# Serve the bundle at js/main.js
if (dir.exists("dist/img")) {
  addResourcePath("img", "dist/img")
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```